# What is the correct way to import a js class in vue 3

Tags: javascript, class, import, vuejs3, inertiajs

I want to import a class from the .js file to my component in vue 3 but it throws me an error of

> **[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of render function    at...**
>
> **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $setup.Utils.capitalizeFirstLetter is not a function**

I understand that the problem derives from how I use it in the component, I am working on a Laravel 8 application with jetstream and inertia js

My class utils.js

```
export class Utils {
   capitalizeFirstLetter(str) {
     //code...
   }
}
```

My component in vue

```
<template>
     <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ Utils.capitalizeFirstLetter(title) }}
      </h2>
</template>

<script>
import { Utils } from '@/utils/utils.js'

export default {  
  setup() {

      return {
          Utils
      }
  }
};
</script>
```

Someone who is more expert that can enlighten me

Answer (score 1):

in the end I understood what I was doing wrong, I had to see some examples in vue 2, you just had to instantiate the class in a variable and if you have it accessible to the methods

```
<template>
     <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
        {{ Util.capitalizeFirstLetter(title) }}
      </h2>
</template>

<script>
import { Utils } from '@/utils/utils.js'

export default {  
  setup() {
      const Util = new Utils;

      return {
          Util
      }
  }
};
</script>
```